# Principal ideals generated by elements that are not associates

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $k$ is a field and let $k[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials in 2 variables with $k$-coefficients. Consider the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(x{y^2})=R$.

What are the units in this ring R?

Clearly every non-zero element in $k$ is a unit, as are all elements of the form $a+b(xy)$, where $a$ is a non-zero element of $k$, since $xy$ is a nilpotent element of $R$ ($(xy)^2=x^2y^2=x(xy^2)=0$). Is every unit in $R$ of this form?

Also, why are the elements $x\in R$, and $(x+xy)\in R$ not associates of each other in R? (This is why I was trying to work out the units in $R$).

More general question: Assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity, and assume that $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal in $R$. Let $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ be the radical ideal of the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$. Does the multiplicative group of units in the quotient ring $R/{\mathfrak{a}}$ consist of elements of the form $a+br$ where $a\in{R^{\times}}$, and $r\in{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}}$?

Answer (score 3):

There are more units in $k[x,y]/(xy^2) $ than in $k$. You can easily check that all elements of the form
$$a+b xy,\quad a,b\in k,\;a\ne 0$$
are units because $xy$ is nilpotent.

*Added*: *a partial answer to the new formulation*

By *Jacobson's theorem*, the radical of a (commutative) ring $R$ is the set of elements $x\in R$ such that $1+rx$ is invertible for all $a\in R$.

By an obvious extension, it is also the set of all $x\in R$ such that, for any unit $u$ and any $r\in R$, $u+rx$ is a unit. You can apply Jacobson's theorem to the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak a$.

Comment: Of course! Because a unit + a nilpotent element is always a unit...

Comment: Bernard, Your useful comment (which I voted up) prompted me to modify the question and formulate it more clearly. Please see the reformulated question. Thanks!

Comment: @student: Since your new question differs significantly from the original one, it's advised to pose it as a new, separate question. You might want to check basic examples like $R=\mathbb Z$, $\mathfrak a=(p)$ first.

Comment: I did pose it as a new question, but a reader flagged it as a duplication-which is why I took down my post and combined it with this one!